# Enable destructive backspace in Teraterm

Tags: teraterm

I have an application that communicates via USB over COM and I usually use Putty to develop. Some of the users will use Teraterm instead and want the user experience to be as similar as possible.

In Putty, I can send a 0x7F which is ASCII "DEL" and when that value is echo'd back from my application, Putty does a backspace+delete (destructive backspace). With Teraterm, Backspace sends 0x08 which is ASCII "BS" (backspace) and, as long as the "Transmit DEL by:" box for Backspace Key is not checked, the key is returned as 0x08 without any delete (non-destructive backspace).

Is there any way to enable configuration of Teraterm to move cursor position back one character and delete that character when it receives the 0x08 command?

Answer (score 1):

This has been a long time with no answer, so hopefully you worked through it. I don't understand if this scripted through the teraterm macro or if you are just manually navigating through teraterm.

But if this is for a script (.ttl) file or just a command within teraterm, and you know what string is being sent that needs this, you can do the following:

```
wait "[insert string you are looking for here]"
send 8 127
```

Where 8 means backspace and 127 means delete. Hope that helps. But teraterm will accept multiple ascii codes in one send command. The wait command could also be further rounded out to accept a timer for the wait action before it performs anything. The wait command can also accept up to 10 strings to wait for: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/wait.html

You can also find the ASCII code table for teraterm here: https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/appendixes/ascii.html